# Swapping supremums and integrals

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f \in H^{-1}(S)$, where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is some nice set in space.
Can I exchange supremums and integrals over time here:
$$\sup_{g \in H^1(S)}\int_0^T \langle f, g \rangle_{H^{-1}(S), H^1(S)}\;dt =\int_0^T \sup_{g \in H^1(S)} \langle f, g \rangle_{H^{-1}(S), H^1(S)}\;dt$$

I think so. But what if $g$ has some dependence on $t$? Or is that not allowed?

Comment: What is the relation between $f$ and $y$?

Comment: @HansEngler Sorry it should all be $f$. I edited.

Comment: ... and $S = \Omega$?

Comment: @HansEngler $S = \Omega$, some nice set. No time dependence.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ depends on $t$ and supremum on the right is computed for each $t$, the two sides are not equal, even if $g$ does not depend on $t$.

A simple counterexample can be constructed by taking $T = 2 \pi, f(t) = \sin t \phi$, where $\phi$ is an arbitrary element in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Then if $g \in H^1(\Omega)$, the left hand side is zero, but the right hand side is positive.

If $g$ is allowed to depend on $t$, equality holds, I think.

Comment: Thanks. So if both $f$ and $g$ depend on $t$, it should hold. Seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: @maximumtag Since $t$ has no meaning outside of the integral with respect to $t$, it's impossible for $g$ to depend on $t$ on the left side of the formula.